# Произведение столбцов матрицы

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Есть целочисленная матрица. Нужно определить столбец с минимальным произведением элементов. 
Мой код:

```
import random
n=int(input('Введите кол-во строк матрицы: '))
m=int(input('Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: '))
matrix=[[random.randrange(10) for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
for elem in matrix:
    print(elem)
```

Но как вычесть произведение элементов матрицы и сравнить с последующими столбцами? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче всего это сделать транспонировав матрицу:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

matrix = [[6, 2, 1, 4, 4], [8, 5, 6, 6, 1], [7, 7, 6, 5, 8]]

res = min(zip(*matrix), key=lambda r: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, r))
print(res)
# (4, 1, 8)
```

если нужен индекс столбца:

```
In [56]: res = min(enumerate(zip(*matrix)), key=lambda t: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, t[1]))

In [57]: res
Out[57]: (4, (4, 1, 8))

In [58]: res[0]
Out[58]: 4
```